Create a partitioned Icerberg Table from dbt using Athena Connector
Hope you're doing well.
I'm using dbt with AWS Athena to start creating my models, here's an example of my configuration from dbt.
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    table_type = 'iceberg',
    unique_key = ['dt', 'country'],
    partition_by = ['dt', 'country'],
    s3_data_naming = 'schema_table',
    on_schema_change='append_new_columns',
    incremental_strategy='merge'
) }}

The table is indeed created in AWS and the information is stored in the S3 correctly.
However i got some questions so i can tuned better my table:

The partitions [if created correctly] doesn't specify the name of the partitions [dt and country]. See image attached, it shows characters and i can't tell which partition belongs to.

How can i tell if the partitions have been correctly configured?
enter image description here

In both Glue and Lake Formation i can't see the primary_key attribute on dt and country. Is there any way i can configured it within the config() in dbt?.

How can I only specify to add new partitions within the last 2 days [info from the last 2 days], while deleting day by day partitions older than 1 month?


Best Regards,
I've tried all the configurations including partition_by, unique_key and properties = {'partitioning'}.

Iceberg tables are stored in this way to optimize S3 performance. What you see in your screenshot is random prefixes that help spread out the table's data over a wider keyspace. It's a feature, not a bug. Consider Iceberg table storage opaque. It's managed by the Iceberg library, and everything is recorded in the manifests. Don't read out any significance from the locations of the files themselves.
Iceberg tables don't have primary keys. Primary keys are hard, and very expensive to enforce in a data lake setting, and it's also not something that analytics workloads need in general. The unique_key configuration in dbt is the closest thing you will have to a primary key. It basically tells dbt how to formulate updates so that the right row gets updated. You should probably not have the same unique_key as partition_by. If your rows have some kind of ID similar to what you would pick as a primary key in a relational database, use that as your unique_key.
I'm not sure you can tell dbt to delete data. If you want your model to represent a rolling window of time you may be better off using a regular model and recreate the table on every run.
